# express/mongodb: Value not entering the database through $push

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to push a value to mongodb when a route is accessed. When i try it pushing through Mongo Shell, the value is pushed, but when i go to the route, nothing is pushed. The route is something like this

```js
router.post('/course/:userid/step-four/:courseid', function(req, res) {
      Course.findOne({
            "_id": req.params.courseid
          }, function(err, course) {
            if (err) {
              res.send(err);
            } else {
              User.update({
                "_id": ObjectId(req.params.userid)
              }, {
                $push: {
                  courseId: req.params.courseid
                }
              });
```

Note that i'm able to retrieve both url params when i log them in console, but somehow it is not entering into the db. What can i do?

Comment: Use a callback function after your update to see if their are no error

Comment: make sure your end point is being hit correctly (by logging something under that endpoint). And secondly make sure `req.params.courseid` is passes correctly

Comment: Thank you people. When i defined a callback, it worked correctly.